# fatel error check internet connection in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

my app working fine any without problem , i used AsyncTask to get data json and every thing is fine . i want to add code to check internet connection  in my app and i put code under `onCreate` in main activity .

```
val cm = baseContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
val networkInfo = cm.activeNetworkInfo
if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected){

    if (networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){

        Toast.makeText(baseContext,"wifi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    if (networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){

        Toast.makeText(baseContext,"MOBILE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}else {
    Toast.makeText(baseContext,"MOBILE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    this.finish()
}
```

when l put the phone on airplan mode and launching app he is stop working . and crash .

console log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports, PID: 10868
```

main activity

```
package com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.TextView
import com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports.BaghdadAirport.ListAdapteArr
import com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports.BaghdadAirport.ListAdapteDep
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_baghdada_arrivel.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_baghdada_dep.*

import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL
import android.widget.Toast
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.NetworkInfo
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports.BaghdadAirport.FlightsArrivelBeforBGW
import com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports.BaghdadAirport.FlightsDepBeforBGW


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val url = "airport.json"
        Arr().execute(url)


        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val fragmentAdapter = MyPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

        viewpager_main.adapter = fragmentAdapter
        sliding_tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewpager_main)

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        )
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)


        val cm = baseContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val networkInfo = cm.activeNetworkInfo
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected){

            if (networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){

                Toast.makeText(baseContext,"wifi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            if (networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){

                Toast.makeText(baseContext,"MOBILE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(baseContext,"MOBILE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            this.finish()
        }

    }


    //    full class for json api
    inner class Arr : AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

        val progressDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
        val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog, null)
        val message = dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.message_id)
        val dialog = progressDialog.create()

        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()

            dialog.setMessage("يرجى الانتظار")
            dialog.setCancelable(false)
            dialog.show()


        }

        //        for build connection
        override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String?): String {

            var text: String
            val connection = URL(url[0]).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

            try {
                connection.connect()
                text = connection.inputStream.use { it.reader().use { reader -> reader.readText() } }


            } finally {

                connection.disconnect()

            }
            return text
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {

            super.onPostExecute(result)
            handleJson(result)

            dialog.dismiss();

        }

        override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg text: String?) {


        }

        @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
        private fun handleJson(jsonString: String?) {

            val jsonObj = JSONObject(jsonString)
            val result = jsonObj.getJSONObject("result")
            val response = result.getJSONObject("response")
            val airport = response.getJSONObject("airport")
            val pluginData = airport.getJSONObject("pluginData")
            val schedule = pluginData.getJSONObject("schedule")
            val arrivals = schedule.getJSONObject("arrivals")

//            weather data
            val weather = pluginData.getJSONObject("weather")
            val mater = weather.getString("metar")

//            MaterText.text=mater
//        val data = arrivals.getJSONObject("data")
            val jsonArray = JSONArray(arrivals.get("data").toString())

            val list = ArrayList<FlightShdu>()
            var x = 0
            while (x < jsonArray.length()) {

                val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x)



                list.add(
                    FlightShdu(
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("identification").getJSONObject("number").getString(
                            "default"
                        ),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("airline").getString("short"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("status").getJSONObject("generic").getJSONObject(
                            "status"
                        ).getString("text"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("airline").getJSONObject("code").getString("icao"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("time").getJSONObject("scheduled").getString("arrival"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("airport").getJSONObject("origin").getJSONObject(
                            "code"
                        ).getString("iata"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("aircraft").getJSONObject("model").getString("code"),
//                    for more information
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("time").getJSONObject("real").getString("departure"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("time").getJSONObject("estimated").getString("arrival"),
//                    jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("time").getJSONObject("estimated").getString("arrival"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("aircraft").getString("registration"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("status").getJSONObject("generic").getJSONObject(
                            "status"
                        ).getString("diverted"),
                        arrivals.getString("timestamp"),
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("status").getString("icon")


                    )
                )


                x++
            }
            list.forEach(::println)

            var adapter = ListAdapteArr(this@MainActivity, list)
            flight_arrivel_list.adapter = adapter


        }

    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        val id = item.itemId

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        if (id == R.id.flightarrbeforbgw) {

            val intent = Intent(this, FlightsArrivelBeforBGW::class.java)
            this.startActivity(intent)
            return true
        }

        if (id == R.id.flightdepbefrobgw) {
            val intent = Intent(this, FlightsDepBeforBGW::class.java)
            this.startActivity(intent)
            return true
        }
//
//        if (id == R.id.searchflights) {
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Android Menu is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
//            return true
//        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_camera -> {
                // Handle the camera action
            }
            R.id.nav_gallery -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_slideshow -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_manage -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_share -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_send -> {

            }
        }

        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }



}
```

Comment: you looking for internet connectivity check code ?

Comment: yes , l used code above but l got crash

Comment: I have one for if you want you can use it

Answer (score 0):

to avoid fatal error and crash when there is not internet connection ,my mistake is i should put execute() url inside code of check internet connection

```
 val cm = baseContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            val networkInfo = cm.activeNetworkInfo
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected){

                if (networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){


                                        val url = "airport.json"

                    Arr().execute(url)

                }
                if (networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){


                    val url = "airport.json"
                    Arr().execute(url)
                }

            }else {
   val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            builder.setTitle("No internet Connection")
            builder.setMessage("Please turn on internet connection to continue")
            builder.setNegativeButton(
                "close"

            ) { dialog, button -> this.finish() }
            val alertDialog = builder.create()
            alertDialog.show()    


            }
```

now my app working fine =)